# Find Interest rate on account statement in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

i hava table of statement and it has the date,credit,debit and balance column through these i want to find total interest.

```
TRX_DATE     CREDIT      DEBIT        BAL
-------- ---------- ---------- ----------
01-11-18                                0
05-11-18       7500                  7500
08-11-18                  2500       5000
15-11-18      10000                 15000
25-11-18                  9000       6000
30-11-18                  1000       5000
05-12-18       7100                 12100
10-12-18                  2100      10000
20-12-18      20000                 30000
25-12-18                 15000      15000
```

for finding interest :

1. if count_day=next_date-current_date then
2. (4*(sum(count*bal)))/36500

I tried and get row of each `trx` interest but didn't get total or sum of the rows. and while trying sum() on the query error shows ORA-30483: window  functions are not allowed here

```
select ((4*(bal*(trx_date-((lag(trx_date) over (order by trx_date))))))/36500)as interest 
from int i;

interest
------------
78.
```

Comment: ".. `if count_day=next_date-current_date then` ". What do you mean by that ?

Comment: it gets difference between each row to next row of trx_date

Comment: select (trx_date-lag(trx_date)over(order by trx_date))as dd from int

Comment: DD
----------
          
         4
         3
         7
        10
         5
         5
         5
        10
         5
it gives me output like this to multiply with bal

Comment: It would help, if you showed the expected result. You want to multiply 0 by four (days) and 7500 by 3 (days), etc. Yes? And interest is this amount * 4 / 36500? And you want the interest column in your results cumulated? 0, 0, 2.47, 6.30, ...?

Comment: yes about  amount * 4 / 36500 these but i didn't got your point ->multiply 0 by four (days) and 7500 by 3 (days), etc.

Comment: In the first four days the balance is 0, so it 4 * 0 = 0. Then there are three days with balance 7500, so it's 3 * 7500 = 22500. And 22500 * 4 / 36500 = 2.47. Then what is the expected query result? One single value with the total interest sum? Please edit your request and show the expected result.

Comment: yes one single value with total interest sum..22500 * 4 / 36500 = 2.47 like this for all rows and expected result is  total

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution using LEAD

```
SELECT ROUND(4.0 * SUM(bal * days / 36500), 2) as Interest
FROM (
    SELECT bal, NVL(LEAD(trx_date) OVER (ORDER BY trx_date) - trx_date, 0) days
    FROM transaction)
```

This gives an accrued interest of 62.79 for the sample data. Below are the individual interest amounts

```
+----+--------+-------+  
|DAYS|     BAL|    INT|  
+----+--------+-------+  
|   4|       0|      0|  
|   3|    7500|   2.47|  
|   7|    5000|   3.84|  
|  10|   15000|  16.44|  
|   5|    6000|   3.29|  
|   5|    5000|   2.74|  
|   5|   12100|   6.63|  
|  10|   10000|  10.96|  
|   5|   30000|  16.44|  
|   0|   15000|      0|  
+----+--------+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much...@joakim_danielson